# Как создать нумерованный список в Microsoft Word c#?

Tags: c#, office-interop, range

Нужно создать нумерованный список в Word, например:

```
1. Заголовок 1
    1.1. Подзаголовок 1
    1.2. Подзаголовок 2
2. Заголовок 2
    2.2. Подзаголовок 1
```

Вот пример кода. Проблема в том, что не получается создать подпункты заголовка:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add();

Word.Paragraph paragraph = null;
Word.Range range = doc.Range();

app.Visible = true;

paragraph = range.Paragraps.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Заголовок 1";

paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault(Word.WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery);

paragraph.Outdent();

paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Подзаголовок 1";
paragraph.Indent();

paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Подзаголовок 2";
paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Заголовок 2";
paragraph.Outdent();
```

Comment: ваши попытки самому решить вашу проблему?

Comment: Добавил фрагмент кода

Comment: [How to Create Multi-level List Numbering in Word in C#, VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Paragraph/How-to-Create-Multi-level-List-Numbering-in-Word-in-C-VB.NET.html)?

Comment: [Numbered List in Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939995/numbered-list-in-microsoft-word)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала добавить текст в параграф

```
paragraph.Range.Text = "Text";
```

Затем нужно использовать функции SetListLevel() и ApplyListTemplateWithLevel()

```
paragraph.Range.SetListLevel(2);
paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(listTemplate, ContinuePreviousList: true, ApplyTo: WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior: WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior, ApplyLevel: 2);
```

После добавить параграф

```
paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Также нужно настроить уровни шаблона списка под себя.